# JQuery Mobile: 3 Filter Boxed

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I am making a JQuery Mobile web app that uses a listview with a data filter.

When I tap on a menu row, the app loads another screen. When I click the back button, the following visual error sometimes occurs:

I have called the following command in the page's content:

```
$("landmarksList").enhanceWithin();
```

[image: filterError]

Is there a JQuery Mobile command that I can use to rebuild the screen's layout every time it shows?

Comment: you're misusing `.enhanceWithin()` function.

Comment: Do you know of a function that I can use that will privet this from occurring? Or a function that rebuilds the screen every time it becomes visible?